# ASP.Net Core SignInManager lockoutOnFailure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

ASP.Net Core has SignInManager which handles user authentication. One of the methods is `PasswordSignInAsync(string username, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)`. Setting lockoutOnFailure to true should temporarily lock out the user after a certain number of failed login attempts.

Looking at the AspNetUsers table in the database I see the following:

- AccessFailedCount increase by 1 for each failed access, when it hits 5 it rolls over to 0.
- Upon rolling over to 0 LockoutTimeEnd is set to 5 minutes into the future.
- LockoutEnabled however remains 0 even after rollover, and user can continue attempting to log in.

It looks like the intended functionality is to allow 5 login attempts, then lock out the account for 5 minutes.

So my questions are are:

1. How do I set number of allowed failed logins?
2. How do I set the lockout period?
3. Why doesn't the lockout trigger?

Comment: about your 3rd bulltet, it works for default project template, so you have to share some code, for help

Comment: I found out about this. Any user with "LockoutEnabled=false" will never be locked out regardless of "LockoutTimeEnd". While user with "LockoutEnabled=true" will be locked out only if LockoutTimeEnd>DateTime.Now. I had set all users to "LockoutEnabled=false", effectively disabling the whole lockout mechanism.

Comment: How did you set that? when creating a user in register action?

Comment: From SQL `UPDATE AspNetUsers SET LockoutEnabled=0;`

Comment: Ok. So normally, if you do not run custom SQL queries :), with LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers = true (which is default), a newly created user can be locked out. LockoutEnabled will be set to 1.

Comment: Ok, nice to know. :)

Comment: also in PasswordSignInAsync the lockoutOnFailure parameter must be have true, to increase the AccessFailedCount

Comment: Jeeees guys thanks I am reading the comments here because the docs on Microsoft doesn't really explain the meaning of this flag "LockoutEnabledForNewUsers"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 1. How do I set number of allowed failed logins?
> 2. How do I set the lockout period?

Default project template uses an extension method for configuring identity services `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` (in `Startup` class `ConfigureServices` method). There is an overload of this method that you can configure `IdentityOptions`.

Instead of

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

You can use

```
var lockoutOptions = new LockoutOptions()
{
     AllowedForNewUsers = true,
     DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
     MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5
};

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
     {
         options.Lockout = lockoutOptions;
     })
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The above is pointeless because these are the default values of `LockoutOptions`, but you can changes them as you like.